# Covering of $S^2$ with patches that send line segments to geodesic arcs

Tags: differential-geometry

So does there exist surface patches on $S^2$ so that for every line in the coordinate patch is sent to a geodesic on $S^2$. I tried finding such a map but I was unsuccessful. I was wondering if someone could help me out.

**EDIT:** So I tried out the hint and I got the following map

$$f(x,y)=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}})$$.

I don't see why this maps geodesics to line segments. Would you mind explaining a little further Anthony. Thanks.

Comment: Project from the centre of $S^2 \subset R^3$ on to some plane.

Comment: Anthony would you mind explaining a little bit more why this map works?. I don't see why it maps lines to geodesics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the *gnomonic projection*. Fix the standard embedding $\Bbb S^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ and choose a plane $\Pi$ (not intersecting the sphere) which will act as our coordinate plane. Then for any point $p \in \Pi$, let $\phi(p)$ be the unique point in $S^2$ that lies on the line segment joining $p$ to the origin - this $\phi$ then defines a coordinate chart on a hemisphere $H \subset S^2$.

If you take a line $L \subset \Pi$, then there is a unique plane $\Xi$ that contains $L$ and passes through the origin, and we have $\Xi \cap \Pi = L$, $\Xi \cap H = \phi(L)$. Now remember that the geodesics of the sphere are precisely the intersections of the sphere with planes through the origin, so $\phi(L)$ is geodesic.